# Finding position of selected datatype column in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

**this is my dataframe:**

```
c_id  fname  age salary  lname
1      abc   21   21.22   yyy
2      def   41   23.4    zzz
```

i need to display the position of the column name with respect to datatype. so my output should be:

```
**FOR INT:**

col_name  position 
c_id       0
age        2

**for str:**

col_name  position 
fname        1
lname        4

**for float:**

col_name  position 
salary     3
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can just create a dataframe from the dtypes and reset the index to get the positional index number.

```
col_df = (
pd.DataFrame(df.dtypes, columns=["DataType"])
.rename_axis("Column")
.reset_index()
.rename_axis("Position")
)

          Column DataType
Position                 
0           c_id    int64
1          fname   object
2            age    int64
3         salary  float64
4          lname   object
```

---

```
print(col_df[col_df['DataType'] == 'object'])

         Column DataType
Position                
1         fname   object
4         lname   object
```

Comment: that looks good, what if i need to print another column called max_length which prints the string which has max length..

Comment: max_len = max(df[col], key=len)   which prints the max string length but how can i add this as a column in the above data frame output.

Comment: @pooja please provide a sample

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61998848/print-column-position-of-a-dataframe/61998902?    please use the link i have posted the sample.

Comment: @pooja I don't see anything related to a string

Comment: just check the link, the strings i have mentioned as string 1 and string 2...

Answer (score 0):

You could use .dtypes method on DataFrame

```
df.dtypes
>>> Name      object
    Age        int64
    City      object
    Marks    float64
    dtype: object

df.dtypes['Name']
>>> object
```