# print column position of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, list, numpy, dataframe

this is my dataframe:

```
c_id  string1  age  salary   string2
1      apple    21    21.22   hello_world
2      orange   41   23.4     world
3      kiwi     81   20.22    hello
```

i need to print the string value which has max_len along with the column datatype, name and its position.so my expected output should be:

```
position c_name   c_dtype  max_len
1        string1   object  orange
4        string2   object  hello_world
```

i tried these concept to print string value based on its max length.

```
for col in df.select_dtypes([np.object]):
    max_len = max(df[col], key=len)
    print('prints col_name:', col) 
    print('prints the datatype ',df[col].dtype)
    print('prints the maximum length string value',max_len)
```

i need to merge all these and should get my expected output as mentioned above.

Comment: i mean the index of column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Index.get_loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_loc.html) for position of column:

```
out = []    
for col in df.select_dtypes([np.object]):
    max_len = max(df[col], key=len)
    print('position:', df.columns.get_loc(col))  
    print('prints col_name:', col) 
    print('prints the datatype ',df[col].dtype)
    print('prints the maximum length string value',max_len)

    out.append({'position':df.columns.get_loc(col), 
                'c_name': col, 'c_dtype':df[col].dtype, 'max_len': max_len})

df1 = pd.DataFrame(out)
print (df1)
   position   c_name c_dtype      max_len
0         1  string1  object       orange
1         4  string2  object  hello_world
```

List comprehension solution:

```
out = [{'position':df.columns.get_loc(col), 
        'c_name': col, 'c_dtype':df[col].dtype, 'max_len': max(df[col], key=len)} 
        for  col in df.select_dtypes([np.object])]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(out)
print (df1)
   position   c_name c_dtype      max_len
0         1  string1  object       orange
1         4  string2  object  hello_world
```

Comment: along with that i want to add the column position also.

Comment: for the above dataframe the column string 1 was in 1st  position, string 2 was in 4 th position